# Reference values from a excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets. Say SheetA and SheetB

The **SheetB** uses the cell values from **SheetA** to calculate and arrive at a value. There is quite a lot of cell referencing inside the **SheetB** to calculate and arrive at a result. This result then has to be displayed as an output on **SheetA**.

1. **SheetB** uses value from a cell in **SheetA**
2. Calculation is performed on **SheetB**, resulting an output
3. Output is displayed on **SheetA**

Initially, I used just cell referencing to calculate the result and displaying it on the **SheetA**. However, there are multiple places in **SheetA** where the calculation has to be performed by sending the value to **SheetB**

Excel experts any ideas on how to proceed on this?

Is there a way I can make the entire worksheet as a function and keep calling the sheet passing the required parameters?

Comment: Can't you use VBA?

Comment: Layout your information and calculations in a table such that you can copy down or to the right as required to get repeated calculations done

Comment: @ForwardEd : Care to elaborate

Comment: In the absence of any tangible information on what your formulas in SheetB do, it's pretty much impossible to give you advise other than 'Restructure your workbook'. How 'bout fleshing out your question so it is answerable.

Comment: ":make the entire worksheet as a function and keep calling" > IMHO : cannot. Unless u specified the calculation multiple times ( 1 time per each call ).